# How to set a background on an alarm clock app

Tags: android, android-alarms

In an Android alarm clock app that I want to develop, I want to allow people to have a custom image as the app's background when it goes off, rather than having the device's stock background, but I don't know how to go about it. It might actually be really simple but I am still a beginner (a shocker I know) so yeah does anyone have any ideas??

Just in case people are getting confused, I DON'T want the app to change the person home screen wallpaper, just the alarms background

I haven't started the app yet because as I said I need to know this one thing before i spend a few weeks developing

Kind Regards

Ryan

Answer (score 2):

I believe this question has been asked multiple times before. Did you try searching the site prior to asking? It is a pretty basic question if you are just trying to change the background wallpaper on Android.

**Edit based on your comment:** See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3307090/how-to-add-background-image-to-activity).

Comment: I'm not talking about a simple wallpaper changer though, unless that code will work for setting the alarms clock actual background when the the alarm goes off at the desired time? i only ask because i don't want the app to change the person home screen wallpaper