# Android: Changing program background with image from gallery

Tags: android

So I want to have the option for the user to change programs background with his own picture from gallery. I have a button and I saved the images as bitmaps and tried to use button.setBackgroundDrawable() to do so but it puts the picture over the button so that only the button text can be seen and it also doesn't make the picture fullscreen. Here's some of my code:

```
if (bitmap != null) {
                bitmap.recycle();
            }
            InputStream stream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(data.getData());
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);
            stream.close();

            BitmapDrawable ob = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);
            button.setBackgroundDrawable(ob);
```

And I have xml setup like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="0dp"
android:paddingLeft="0dp"
android:paddingRight="0dp"
android:paddingTop="0dp"
tools:context="com.example.proba.MainActivity" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="pickImage"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="106dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="192dp"
    android:text="Button" />
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a look [at this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3307191/2346169), since you are getting the image from gallery, you can give your root layout an id and then set background like `rootlayout.setBackgroundDrawable(ob);`

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked. I will have to make some tests but it looks that this is the solution.

Comment: Ok i did, sry im new to this website.